# Cannot merge back space left by bootcamp

Tags: high-sierra, storage

So, I uninstall Windows 10 using Bootcamp, but now I got this 'free storage' space that I cannot merge back again, I've tried everything that's already answered in this forum for this type of questions, since booting in recovery mode to running the `sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer /dev/disk0s2 0` command on the terminal

If I tried to do it in diskutility I got the following error
[image]

And if I try to run the command to resize my partition I got the following error:
[image]

Here's an extra pic of my diskutil list command:
[image]

And my diskutil
[image]

Any suggestion ? I'm running High Sierra Version 10.13.6

Comment: If you reissue the resize command and have it work on `disk0s1` instead of `disk0s2` do you still get the same error? It might be a typo in the text above or it might be the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to grow the APFS container, not the physical drive that it's on (as this would be impossible, obviously). This can't be disk0, and it looks like it's disk1 in your screenshots, so `diskutil ap resizeContainer disk0s1 0` should do what you want.

There is no `disk0s2` to operate on, so that should error based on your excellent details in the question.

It’s safe to do a live resize of the container.

Comment: Got the following error from running diskuti ap resizeContainer disk1 0 https://imgur.com/a/QlsXcbK, this is a screenshot from the diskutil ap list https://imgur.com/a/1b5Ev0I

Comment: I think you’re close. I wouldn’t try to grow `disk1` but what about resizing `disk0s1` container  - that seems the correct call here. +1 for the answer.

Comment: Are you sure you ran `diskutil ap resizeContainer disk1` and not `diskutil ap resizeContainer disk1s0 ...`?

Comment: Forget about all the synthesized sizes in `disk1` none of those are hard limits. That shows how much space is allocated, not how much free space is left. Let’s get back to operating on disk0 which is the actual container. See my edit to your answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm totally sure @user3052786

Comment: @bmike disk1 is a reference to the container stored on disk0s1, but using the disk1 reference is somehow better I think.. I can't remember how exactly

Comment: @bmike So, I should run 'diskutil resizeContainer disk0s1 0' ?

Comment: @BrianPolanco Did you recently turn on FileVault encryption??

Comment: @user3052786 I actually did turn it off to test some commands and right now it's in the process of turning on

Comment: It might just be me but I would hold off on making changes until it's not mid-live-de/encryption... Maybe that's also what's causing the errors you're getting?

Comment: Don't think so cause i tried to run some of the commands from when the filevault was turn off, but will try after is done encrypting

Comment: @user3052786 after fileVault was done I ran diskutil ap resizeContainer disk0s1 0 and worked like a charm, thanks for everything. bmike♦ you too as well.